# Show only the first letters, three dots and the last N letter of a span

Tags: css

If I've a very long text like this (for example in a table):

```
<p class='line'>
    <span class='fixed1'>FIXED</span>
    <span class='long_text'>This is my very very very very long text</span>
    <span class='fixed2'>FIXED</span>
</p>
```

By default the `<p>` width is 100% and if the text is longer than the screen it's showed on multi lines. Instead I want it in a single line where only the last N letter are showed.

Here some example:

Screen large enough:

```
FIXED This is my very very very very long text FIXED
```

Screen not enough large, text overflow.

```
FIXED This is my ve... text FIXED
```

I can obtain something similar using:

```
span.long_text {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Is it possible to obtain the effect I described? How?

Comment: I think it is possible, but not with CSS only... You will need javascript, probably...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `white-space: nowrap` to force it to stay in a single line.

`text-overflow: ellipsis` will replace the end of your content with '...' when overflow occurs. However span must be a block for text-overflow to work, so set its display property to inline-block or block.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1bmdu5xd/

Comment: Ok, but I'd like something like this: `FIXED This is my ve... text FIXED`
Not `FIXED This is my ve... FIXED`

Answer (score 0):

Ellipsis only work with single line things so that's OK here. The problem is with those "N letter".

Here's a starter with `:after` (you must have your N last letters in some CSS. Suboptimal => https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/vWMePJ?editors=0100

```css
.line {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 240px;
}
.line > * {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.long_text {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: yellow;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}
.long_text::after {
  content: "g text";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class='line'>
    <span class='fixed1'>FIXED</span>
    <span class='long_text'>This is my very very very very long text</span>
    <span class='fixed2'>FIXED</span>
</p>
```

It could be `content: attr(data-last-letters)` and `<span class='long_text' data-last-letters="g text">` which now works in most browsers.
Or `background-image: -moz-element(#someId);` that [copy-paste an element elsewhere](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/mozelement/) and that only works in Firefox (for the past 7 years: won't work cross-browser anytime soon I guess).